# Separate code for neural network in different files

Tags: neural-network, keras

I just finished my 300 lines program in which I trained neural network in Keras for pedestrian detection. I would like to separate it in the project but I don't know how to do that. What is the best way to separate the code for Machine learning algorithm in different files so that somebody who see my code can see every file not too big?

Comment: Hi there, you can see Different repos on GitHub for basis of code division... Generally it's like you import modules at one place, then files and all the Preprocessing at second and the model at third and then testing section  or something equivalent to this..

Answer (score 0):

There are distinct steps in deep learning modeling. Each step could be its own function or its own .py file/module.

Common steps:

1. Data loading
2. Define model architecture
3. Hyperparameter tuning
4. Training final model
5. Prediction on new data